# ExpressJS static files

Tags: node.js

Below image depicts my node js application directory structure in windows OS.

[image]

In express.js file I have mentioned

```
app.use( 'static', express.static('../bower_components/'));
```

I would like to refer to static files bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css which are in /bower_components/bootstrap folder in my view file which is in /views/users/index.js.

I have mentioned below 2 lines in my view file , but it's not working.

```
<link href="../static/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="../static/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Please let me know what needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Your path in the view should be

```
<link href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have something which is similar to yours.. Maybe this could help you:

```
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
var path = require('path'),
        fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http')
...  
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

My view look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
 </head>
<body class="container">

<header>
    <% include ../partials/header %>
</header>

<main>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h3>Welcome in Dubai!,</h3>
    </div>
</main>

<footer>
    <% include ../partials/footer %>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

To give you more information about my folder structure. I have a folder called **views** with two subfolders **pages** and **partials**

Best regards,
Nazar